# Consulta Hibernate sqlRestriction

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Buenos días tengo un problema al hacer una consulta con Hibernate, la cosa es que me gustaría juntar dos consulta en una y he mirado de intentarlo con joins y demás pero ni idea.
Dejo las consultas haber si me podéis orientar por favor, lo que necesito es el resultado de cada una de ellas juntos.
Gracias de antemano.

CONSULTA 1:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction(
    "id_oferta in(select idoferta from nx_ofertas_candidatos where idstudent=? and select_auto=1 and select_manual=1 and interesado=0)",
    idStudentInteres,
    Hibernate.LONG));
```

CONSULTA 2:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction(
    "id_oferta not in (select idoferta from nx_ofertas_candidatos where idstudent=? and nointeresado=0)",
    idStudentInteres,Hibernate.LONG));
```

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que tus sqlrestriction funcionan, podrias envolverlos en criterions y luego usar la condicion OR para retornar el disjunction de las dos expresiones.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Student.class)

Criterion criterion = Restrictions.sqlRestriction("id_oferta in(select idoferta from nx_ofertas_candidatos where idstudent=? and select_auto=1 and select_manual=1 and interesado=0)", idStudentInteres, Hibernate.LONG);

Criterion criteron2 = Restrictions.sqlRestriction("id_oferta not in (select idoferta from nx_ofertas_candidatos where idstudent=? and nointeresado=0)",idStudentInteres,Hibernate.LONG);

Criteron mergeCriterion = Restrictions.or(criterion,criterion2);

criteria.add(mergeCriterion);

List list = criteria.list();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda! me ha sido muy útil

Comment: Si esta respuesta resolvió tu problema, puedes marcarla como [aceptada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) dando click en el icono de `aceptar(check)` que aparece al lado izquierdo de la respuesta que elijas. Toma en cuenta que esta es una comunidad de programadores y en el futuro podría ser de gran ayuda.